# Charge of an orientifold plane

Tags: string-theory, charge, branes

Orientifold projection of open-string states (with $SO(32)$ Chan-Paton charges) of IIB superstring theory is said to result in an orientifold 9-plane with $\pm 16$ D9 brane charge. My question is why 16? Is it related to the rank of $so(32)$ algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from R-R tadpole cancellation.
If you do the calculation (I recommend [1, Chapter 9.4]) you see that the tadpoles cancel if for each O9-plane we add 32 D9-branes.
Therefore $q_{O9} = -32\, q_{D9}$ *in the double cover* ("upstairs geometry").

After the orientifold projection we are left with half as many D-branes with twice the charge, hence
$$ q_{O9} = -16\, q_{D9} $$
in the orientifold.

More remarks (see [1, Chapter 10.6]):

- For general $Op$-planes, the result is
  $$ q_{Op} = -2^{p-4} q_{Dp} $$
  (in the upstairs geometry).
- If we consider more general orientifold projections $\Omega (-1)^F$ (where $F$ is the fermion number), we can indeed have
  $$ q_{Op} = \pm 2^{p-4} q_{Dp} $$
  like you wrote.

> [1] Blumenhagen, R., D. Lüst, and S. Theisen: Basic Concepts of String Theory.